# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. problems with plugins cordova?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

This error is thrown while createDB is called in SQLite DB plugin in Ionic4:

```
> common.js:297 Native: tried accessing the SQLite plugin but Cordova is
> not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a
> device/simulator cordovaWarn @ common.js:297 home.page.ts:21
> TypeError:  Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at
> HomePage.createDB (home.page.ts:28)
```

this is my home.page.ts:

Comment: add some code please

Comment: I think you are trying to execute ionic serve as sqlite DB plugin a native plugin you will have to deploy it to a device/emulator.